# Suppression of braces auto-scale in Latex

Tags: scaling, braces

I often use the `\hat` function in equations and noticed that the auto-scaling of Latex selects the bigger braces.

Example: The inline formula `$Z(\beta) = \tr(\exp(-\beta \hat{H}))$` gives the following result:

[image: Example formula]

In my opinion the normal brace size would be most suitable. Is there any nice way to suppress the auto-scaling of Latex when using `\hat`, `\bar`etc. ?

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Did you mean to write `$Z(\beta)=\tr\left(\exp\left(-\beta \hat{H}\right)\right)$` as the code chunk that gives rise to the screenshot you posted?

Comment: No, I used my version above.

Comment: The issue is that the code you posted does *not* generate the screenshot you posted -- at least not under pdfLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: I use pdflatex ... is it possible that this behavior is induced by a included package?

Comment: Is *is* possible... Please tell us which math- or font-related packages are loaded in your document and which other commands in the preamble may affect the sizing of parentheses in math mode.

Comment: amssymb,amsmath,mathtools,physics,bm,dsfont

Comment: How is `\tr` defined? Please check if `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{amsmath} \DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr} \begin{document} $Z(\beta)=\tr(\exp(-\beta\hat{H}))$ \end{document}` creates large parentheses in your TeX distribution. (Hint: It shouldn't.)

Comment: It is a definition of the physics package. https://ctan.net/macros/latex/contrib/physics/physics.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for mentioning in a comment that your document loads the `physics` package. Indeed, this package automatically sizes parentheses (and other "fence" symbols such as square brackets and curly braces) without the need for `\left` and `\right`.

To achieve your formatting objective, you could use the `\smash` command, which removes height and depth from its argument. Sure enough, the parentheses placed around `\smash{\hat{H}}` aren't enlarged. A slightly less sweeping version of this would be `\smash[t]{\hat{H}}`. (If your TeX distribution isn't up to date, you may need to load the `amsmath` package to use `\smash` with the `[t]` modifier.)

I suggest you perform a global search-and-replace in your editor of all instances of `\hat{H}` and change them to `\smash[t]{\hat{H}}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{physics} 
\begin{document} 
$\exp(-\beta\hat{H})$ vs.\ $\exp(-\beta\smash{\hat{H}})$ vs.\ $\exp(-\beta\smash[t]{\hat{H}})$
\end{document}
```

Comment: The [t] modifier removes the expansion of the symbol above the line, right? And do you think it is useful to set \renewcommand{\hat}[1]{\smash[t]{\hat{#1}}}?

Comment: @qntdni - that's correct. For the case of  `\hat{H}`, using `\smash` or `\smash[t]` makes no difference. It *might* make a difference for, say, `\hat{y}` (since the `y` glyph has a descender component).

Comment: Thank you Mico, you helped me a lot! :)

Answer (score 3):

This is the problem with using a package such as `physics` that inflicts automatic sizing of fences to every user in every formula.

In theory, according to the package documentation, you could do with

```latex
Z(\beta) = \tr\big(\exp\big(-\beta \hat{H}))
```

but, unfortunately, this breaks, producing

[image]

so the closing fences are not balanced with the opening ones and a lot of space is added.

Leave the package alone and you'll be glad having done it.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}

\begin{document}

\[
Z(\beta) = \tr(\exp(-\beta \hat{H}))
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The syntax is natural and no oversizing happens. In the case you want to get slightly bigger size for the outer braces (but it's not at all necessary), do

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}

\begin{document}

\[
Z(\beta) = \tr\bigl(\exp(-\beta \hat{H})\bigr)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I mainly use the physics package because of the bra-ket notation and I couldn't find another package that provides those tools. Do you know a suitable package?

Comment: @qntdni You might try `braket`